# Verifiying if a number is prime or Not from a List of elements

Tags: python

I need to test whether the elements in an array are prime or not by individually verifying them and printing the same for them .

For this I need to take the number of elements 
Accept the elements in an array 
than I need to verify if the element in an array is prime or not

**Please find my code below:**

```
T = int(raw_input())
arr=[]
for i in range(0,T):
    arr.append(int(raw_input()))

for n in arr:
    for j in range(2, n):

        if n % j == 0:
            print 'Not prime'
            break

        else: 
            print "Prime"
            break
```

**Input given:**

```
2
31
33
```

**Expected output:**

```
   Prime
   Not prime
```

**My Output:**

```
Prime
Prime
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code you are trying to print prime or not prime every single iteration of the loop. What you really want to do is loop through the numbers and if your number is divisible the number is not prime, if you manage to loop through the entire list without returning, then you know the number is prime.

This is best solved using an isPrime function

Put this at the top of your code

```
def isPrime(num):
    for i in range(2,num):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

And then change the bottom to this:

```
for n in arr:
    if isPrime(n):
        print("Prime")
    else:
        print("Not prime")
```

Comment: Although there are better ways to identify prime numbers, this is the only answer so far that splits the decision-making into its own function _and_ shows how to call that function in the "for each number..." loop.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Yeah you don't really need to check up to num you can check up to sqrt(num) and there's a bunch of other optimization for isPrime functions, but for simplicity I decided not to use those.

Comment: @Racialz  thanks man , your code helps. However i had to made somechanges to it to optimize it a bit more:import math
T = int(raw_input())
arr=[]
for i in range(0,T):
    arr.append(int(raw_input()))

def isPrime(num):
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

for n in arr:
    if n==1:
        print "Not prime"
    elif isPrime(n):
        print("Prime")
    else:
        print("Not prime")

Answer (score 3):

You're not looping through all the candidates since you always break on the first iteration, no matter the  modulo. Instead break only in case that number is not a prime and if the loop completes then the number is prime:

```
for j in range(2, n):
    if n % j == 0:
        print 'Not prime'
        break
else: 
    print "Prime"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [AKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) Algorithm:

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return "Prime"
    if n == 3:
        return "Prime"
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return "Not Prime"
    if n % 3 == 0:
        return "Not Prime"
    i = 5
    w = 2
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            return "Not Prime"
        i += w
        w = 6 - w
    return "Prime"
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us run the code manually for the input 33. 
As it enters the inner for loop `for j in range(2,n)` it exits after checking for j=2, since, 33%2 == 0 is not true, it enters the else statement, prints "Prime" and exits the inner for loop.

So the correct code would be :

```
T = int(raw_input())
arr=[]
for i in range(0,T):
    arr.append(int(raw_input()))

for n in arr:
    i = 0 # check variable = 1 if n is found to be prime else 0
    for j in range(2, n):

        if n % j == 0:
            i = 1 # found that n is prime. So set i to 1 
            print 'Not prime'
            break

    if i == 0: # check if n did not turn out to be divisible by any number 
        print 'prime'
```

**Additional info :** You can just check from `2` to `square_root(n)`(`x**0.5` in python) instead of checking up to `n` if you want to speed up your code.